# How to find a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ to show that $a = df$.

Tags: analysis, manifolds

I am a masters student and this question was asked in my exercise in Manifolds course.

> Let $a= (2x+y\cos(xy)) dx +x \cos(xy) dy$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ . Show that $a$ is closed. Also show that $a$ is exact by finding a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$  with $a= df$.

I have proved that $a$ is closed. But I am not able to prove that $a$ is exact because I don't have a strategy on what is to be done in this type of questions where exactness is to be proved.

*Can  you please help me by letting me know what strategy is to be used to prove exactness?*

For reference,I am following my class notes only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a function $f(x,y)$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x+y\cos{(xy)}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x\cos{(xy)}$. Any function $f(x,y)$ whose partial derivative with respect to $x$ is $2x+y\cos{(xy)}$ is of the form $f(x,y) = x^2 + \sin{(xy)} + g(y)$. Then $ x\cos{(xy)} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x\cos{(xy)} + g'(y)$, from where you conclude that $g'(y)=0$, hence $g(y) = c$ for some constant $c$. Therefore $f(x,y) = x^2+\cos{(xy)} + c$.

This method is more systematic then anti-differentiating both and trying to match the results; it will also help you with exact one-forms on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 4):

It is known that $$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$$
So you want to antidifferentiate $2x+x\cos xy$ with respect to $x$, and antidifferentiate $y\cos xy$ with respect to $y$, and you want to make the results be the same. A little trial and error will likely get you there.

(Remember that when antidifferentiating w.r.t. $x$, the integration constant is a function of $y$ and not just a constant, and vice versa.)